# "Can't initialize ESE instance - error -583 JET_errSectorSizeNotSupported" при запуске Remote desktop Licensing

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

Добрый день.Проблема такая: при попытке запустить `Remote desktop Licensing` (`TermServLicensing`), выдается ошибка:

> The following general database error has occurred: "Can't initialize
>   ESE instance - error -583 JET_errSectorSizeNotSupported, The physical
>   sector size reported by the disk subsystem, is unsupported by ESE for
>   a specific file type.."

Как возникла проблема. Вылетел один из `HDD Raid1`, после замены `HDD` и регенерации зеркала появилась сама проблема.

Answer (score 1):

А если попробовать забекапить вначале `c:\Windows\system32\lserver`, создать пустую директорию, ребутнуть и перезапустить `TermServLicensing`. Стремно, но как вариант.